# Clone a Node from Xml and Use it somewhere Else without Xml NS Validation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I am trying to load structures from an Xml File so I can reconstruct it somewhere else.
Most parts are already Parsed and loaded into objects. But some parts are useless and are not getting changed, So I decided to take those nodes in their Hierarchy and take the Node and its decendants and keep them as string.

Later I should be able to make an XmlElement or XmlFragment from that string and reattach it to the xml file I am making.

The loading part is fine so far. I Can copy the selected part and hold it as a XmlNode. But for reattaching it I have to convert it to an xmlElement and This is where CustomXmlNamespaces ruins everything. The namespaces are loaded in the complete xml document but when I take a fragment of file, it obviously doesn't contain the namespaces.

When I want to Load the fragment string it prompts me with

> System.Xml.XmlException: ''mxswa' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1,
>   position 2.'

So The xml string is like:

```
<mxswa:Workflow.Variables>
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:Dictionary(x:String, mcw:InteractionActivityResult)" Default="[New Dictionary(Of System.String, Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.InteractionActivityResult)]" Name="InteractionResponses" />
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:Dictionary(x:String, mxs:EntityCollection)" Default="[New Dictionary(Of System.String, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection)]" Name="QueryResults" />
</mxswa:Workflow.Variables>
```

And The loading code is this:

```
XmlDocumentFragment fragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragment.InnerXml = xmlString;
arguments.AppendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: The issue is with the xmlString variable which is not valid xml.  It doesn't contain the namespace.

Comment: ofcourse xmlString doesn't contain the namespaces, it is a fragment from middle of the xmldocument. I want it to be cloned in the middle the way it is.

Comment: It depends on how you are extracting the the xml from parent if it contains the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I seem to got it to work.

As I searched everywhere and almost anyway possible.

I finally managed to make t work by using a tool which is not looking at the namespace at all.

I use HtmlAgilityPack to parse and recreate the xml and it worked like a charm!

The code here is the magic of how it does it!

```
Arguments = xmlNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();
            if(Arguments != null)
        {
            HtmlNode arguments = doc.CreateElement(XamlNodeType.GetXamlElementName() + ".Arguments");

            arguments.AppendChild(XmlFragment);
            el.AppendChild(arguments);

        }
```